# Make from many Variables an SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, variables, mysqli

```
<?php
    $kid = $_SESSION["kid"];
    $sql = "SELECT Gericht_ID FROM `warenkorb` WHERE Kunde_ID = '$kid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $_SESSION['row_gid'] = $row["Gericht_ID"];
            print $_SESSION['row_gid']; // he return me here 2 9 10 11     
        }
    }
    print $_SESSION['row_gid']; // but here just only 11
?>
```

My question is how can i save the value in a `SESSION` with all that numbers 2 9 10 11 not only 11 ?

Comment: `$_SESSION['row_gid'][]= $row["Gericht_ID"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change from

```
$sql = "SELECT Gericht_ID FROM `warenkorb` WHERE Kunde_ID = '$kid'";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT group_concat(Gericht_ID separator ',') as Gericht_ID FROM `warenkorb` WHERE Kunde_ID = '$kid'";
```

Comment: i want to work with this variables and i don't need than an ' ,' i will try to work just only with '' without place

Comment: so you don't need comma but need space between id?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$_SESSION['row_gid'][]` and then print `$_SESSION['row_gid']` outside loop.